# Can't display at full resolution on an external monitor from my MacBook

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, osx-leopard, external-display

I have a 24" Asus V246H and a new MacBook ($999 one). I am trying to display to display to my Asus at 1080p via VGA. So I boot up with the lid closed and the external monitor plugged in. Everything boots up fine, but the resolution is really low. So I go in and change the resolution to be 1920x1080. My monitor then has a blue box on it that says "OUT OF RANGE". Lower resolutions like 1024x768 work, but 1680x1050 doesn't.

If I try mirroring my displays, the entire external monitor AND the entire laptop screen is completely garbled. I can make out some colors, but it is completely unusable.

I am suspecting that it simply won't work via VGA, but I don't want to buy another adapter, and my PC is using the DVI port.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble getting my MacBook to output video to an external display as well. I had roughly the same thing happen with a DVI connection, so I don't think the VGA connection is what's causing the problem.

Try this:

1. Put the MacBook to sleep.
2. Plug the external display adapter (Mini DisplayPort to VGA) into the MacBook.
3. Insert a USB device into the MacBook (a mouse, a flash drive, whatever.)

The MacBook should wake up and output video to the external display at the native resolution of the external display. At least, that's what happens with mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this freeware app for Mac

Display Maestro 1.1.2

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/displaymaestro.html